# Google Cloud Billing: How can I configure the time to send budget notifications

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I have read through the Budget Alert document here: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets#delivery_guarantees has said that:

> Budget notifications will be sent multiple times per day with the current status of your budget.

And here: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/better-cost-control-with-google-cloud-billing-programmatic-notifications
also mentioned that Cloud Billing sends budget notifications multiple times per day

> Set up a Cloud Function to listen to budget notifications and trigger an action.
>   Cloud Billing sends budget notifications multiple times per day, so you will always have the most up-to-date information on your spending.

I want to ask what **"sends budget notifications multiple times per day"** mean?

For example:
I have a threshold rule of 50%. When I break the rule of 50%, I will get budget notifications and this notification will be sent multiple times a day, right. Can I know the exact time when they send? (eg. 3 hours at a time or what...)

How can I configure the time to send budget notifications? (eg: once per day)

**=========== UPDATE 29.11**

After one day from the time I enabled budget-alert, I received budget notifications multiple times (about 30 min at  a time) 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM2pO.png)
and my Slack always have a new message (look like spam)

Please help me, how can I configure the time to send budget notifications? (eg: once per day)

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to receive budget notification only once per day or specific time?
It would be good if you get notification instantly when configured threshold is reached so you can review or take some action.

You can programmatically receive budget notifications. Budget events can be pushed to PubSub and then can be consumed by Cloud function (event-driven) or Scheduler (specific time).
Cloud Function or Scheduler can then send notification to email/slack or other channel.
This article should be helpful https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to receive budget notification only once per day or specific time because after 1 day I enabled budget-alert, I received a lot of message from budget-alert and (about 30 min at a time) my Slack always have a new message :( But in budget-alert document or console, I never see where to config the time to receive budget notification

Comment: If you are getting too many alerts than I would suggest to review alert rules rather getting alert once a day.

Comment: Budget alerts purpose is to notify when you are going beyond set budget. For example, if you set a budget notification to alert you when daily spend goes around X amount. Now if you only receive alert once a day at specific time (say 8PM) then after 8PM if any job or process tries to use more resources and cost 2X amount or more than you will get notifications next day and by the time those processes might have incurred significant cost. Alert notification are generally meant to be real time.

Comment: If you really need to get once a day notification then you can have a Cloud Scheduler job which runs once a day at specific time and consume all PubSub message and sends you one notification

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programmatically in the cloud function. Set it to only post messages on slack if a condition is satisfied.

Example code from [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#functions_billing_limit-nodejs):

```
exports.notifySlack = async pubsubEvent => {
  const pubsubAttrs = pubsubEvent.attributes;
  const pubsubData = Buffer.from(pubsubEvent.data, 'base64').toString();
  const budgetNotificationText = `${JSON.stringify(
    pubsubAttrs
  )}, ${pubsubData}`;

 if({someCondtion} {
    await slack.chat.postMessage({
      token: BOT_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      channel: CHANNEL,
      text: budgetNotificationText,
    });

    return 'Slack notification sent successfully';
  }
 return 'Function triggered';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found is using Google Cloud Storage to persist the last alert sent (to slack or wherever else).
To do so I created a Cloud Storage Bucket in the same project and added a single text file into it named as follow (it includes the budget ID just in case I want to alert on multiple budget in the future):

```
last_alert_<budgetId>.txt
```

containing a single line with the values:

```
0.5 - 2023-09-01T07:00:00Z
```

that is to say the values for the following budget alert message keys with an hyphen in between:

```
<alertThresholdExceeded> - <costIntervalStart>
```

I then added all I need to interact with this file:

```
STORAGE_CLIENT = storage.Client()
BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket_name_you_picked'
FILE_NAME = 'last_alert_<budgetId>.txt'
BUCKET = STORAGE_CLIENT.bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
BLOB = BUCKET.blob(FILE_NAME)
```

(Do not forget to add google-cloud-storage==2.11.0 to the requirements.txt file if needed.)

And finally wrote a function comparing the alert received with the latest alert stored in cloud storage, returning False when the alert was already sent, and True when the alert was not sent yet. If the alert was not sent yet, the function also overwrite the last alert file in cloud storage to update its value.

```
def check_current_alert(alert_data):

    # gather datapoints on the current alert
    threshold = str(alert_data.get("alertThresholdExceeded"))
    interval_start = alert_data.get("costIntervalStart")
    current_alert = threshold + " - " + interval_start

    # retrieves the value stored in cloud storage
    last_alert = BLOB.download_as_string().decode('UTF-8')

    # compares the current alert with the last alert
    # stored in cloud storage
    if last_alert == current_alert:
        return False
    else:
        # if both values are not matching, updates the 
        # file in cloud storage
        BLOB.upload_from_string(current_alert)
        return True
```

Finally, I just had to include this function as suggested above by @Adrian Mole:

```
if check_current_alert(notification_data):
    try:
        SLACK_CLIENT.api_call(...)
    except SlackApiError:
        print("Error posting to Slack")
else:
    print("Alert already posted to Slack")
```